# How does LD_PRELOAD update the library function

Tags: linux, elf, loader, libc, ld-preload

I know we can use the `LD_PRELOAD` trick to replace a libc function, e.g., `malloc()`. So how exactly `LD_PRELOAD` works? Does it replace the GOT/PLT entry?

Answer (score 1):

It puts the preloaded library at the start of the symbol search path.  This way, all references to `malloc` are bound to its implementation, and not the implementation in libc.

In glibc, you can see the code in `elf/rtld.c` (the call to `_dl_map_object_deps`) and the implementation of the `_dl_map_object_deps` function in `elf/dl-deps.c`.